# British Mathematical Olympiad - December 2001 - Round 1 - Question 4

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Twelve people are seated around a circular table. In how many ways
can six pairs of people engage in handshakes so that no arms cross?
(Nobody is allowed to shake hands with more than one person at once.)

I don't even understand what this question is asking. My best guess is that people can shake hands over the table (i.e. with someone on the opposite to them on the table) but that seems like something they'd mention in the brackets at the end.

Comment: I think what they are asking is, given $12$ points on the circle, in how many ways can you draw six chords joining pairs of the points so that none of the chords intersect?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I can't see a systematic way of looking at this though.

Comment: Call the people $1,2,3,\dot,12$ in order around the circle.  $1$ can't shake hands with $3$, since that isolates $2$.  Nor can he shake hand with $5$ since then we'd have to pair off $2,3,4$.  So odds shake hands with evens.  Once you draw the first chord from $1$, you're dealing with line segments, not circles.  Try to do it first for line segments with an even number of points.  Then add up the results over all choices for the initial chord from $1$.

Comment: I shouldn't have said line segments.  They're still arcs, and the chords have to be drawn "inside" them.  All I really mean is that they aren't full circles.  So if $1$ shakes hands with $6$, we have to subproblems, and we need to multiply the possibilities for each to know how many ways there are when $1$ and $6$ shake.

Comment: Can *someone* please edit the title to be a tiny little bit less cryptic?

Comment: @saulspatz If 1 shakes with 3, there's nothing in the question that prevents 2 shaking with 4 *behind the back* of 3.

Comment: @Alnitak Valid point, but I doubt that's what the examiner intended.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't see how that assumption can be made - it happens all the time in real life.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014235/bmo1-2001-problem-4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Number the people around the table $1,\ldots,12$.

As an example, the number of ways that persons $1,\ldots,12$ can engage in handshakes with no arms crossing given that person $1$ is shaking hands with person $6$ is the number of ways that persons $2,\ldots,5$ can handshake with no arms crossing multiplied by the number of ways that persons $7,\ldots,12$ can handshake with no arms crossing. This thought process generalised yields the following recurrence relation, letting $C_n$ be the number of ways that $n$ pairs can handshake, we have
\begin{equation}
C_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n C_{i}C_{n-i},
\end{equation}
where $C_0 = 1$. This is the recurrence relation of the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and has a well known closed form $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {{2n}\choose{n}}$ which can be derived by using its generating function. Thus for us $C_6 = 132$.

Answer (score 9):

Let $S_{2n}$ = ways for for 2n people to shake n pairs, without crossing.

Example, for 4 people ABCD, we have 2 ways: (AB,CD),(AD,BC)

$S_2 = 1$
$S_4 = 2S_2 = 2$
$S_6 = 2S_4 + S_2 S_2 = 4+1 = 5$
$S_8 = 2S_6 + 2S_2 S_4 = 10 + 4 = 14$
$S_{10} = 2S_8 + 2S_2 S_6 + S_4 S_4= 28+10+4 = 42$
$S_{12} = 2S_{10} + 2S_2 S_8 + 2S_4 S_6= 84+28+20 = 132$

Comment: How do you progess from $S_{2n}$ to $S_{2n+2}$ ? Can you explain the relationship there please?

Comment: Say, 10 people, numbered 0 to 9.  If I picked 01, then other 8 people have S8 ways.  If I picked 03, the little gap have S2 ways, the big gap have S6 ways, total S2 S6.  Due to symmetry 01=09, 03=07, so  I doubled 2 terms. → S10 = 2 S8 + 2 S2 S6 + S4 S4